# How to slide new content depending on the link the user clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble with selecting the appropriate class for the content that needs to show.

I need the user to click on a link then have that content slide down on the page.

this is the links...

```
<header>
  <div id="logo">
     WEB DEV
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li id="first"><a id="html5" href="#">HTML5</a></li>
      <li><a id="css3" href="#">CSS3</a></li>
      <li><a id="jquery" href="#">jQuery</a></li>
      <li><a id="php" href="#">PHP</a></li>
      <li><a id="flash" href="#">Flash</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

this is the content I need to slide down depending on which link the user clicked...

```
<div id="content">

                <div id="defaultTabs" class="contentContainer">
                    <div id="defaultTab01" class="topicContent">
                        <a href="http://www.modernizr.com"><img src="images/sitePics/sitePic_Modernizr.png" alt="The Modernizr website - www.modernizr.com"></a>

                        <h3>The Modernizr website - "front-end development done right"</h3>
                        <p>Modernizr is an open-source JavaScript library that helps you build the next generation of HTML5 and CSS3-powered websites.
                        <a href="http://www.modernizr.com">read more</a></p>
                        <div>General</div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="defaultTab02" class="topicContent">
                        <a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops"><img src="images/sitePics/sitePic_codrops.png" alt="Tutorials and articles on web design/development including jQuery, HTML5, and CSS3"></a>

                        <h3>Tutorials on jQuery, HTML5, and CSS3</h3>
                        <p>Codrops is a web development blog that publishes articles and tutorials about web design, programming and usability. The team of Codrops is dedicated to provide useful and qualitative content that is free of charge.
                        <a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops">read more</a></p>
                        <div>General</div>
                    </div>

                </div>   <!-- end div#jqueryTabs -->

                <div id="html5Tabs" class="contentContainer">
                    <div id="html5Tab01" class="topicContent">
                        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp"><img src="images/sitePics/sitePic_HTML501.png" alt="Learn HTML5 at www.w3schools.com"></a>

                        <h3>Learn HTML5 at w3schools.com</h3>
                        <p>Go through an HTML5 tutorial and learn about new elements in HTML5 relating to video, audio, canvas, and forms.  Utilize a reference for HTML5 tags, attributes, and events. 
                        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp">read more</a></p>
                        <div>HTML5</div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="html5Tab02" class="topicContent">
                        <a href="http://www.sitepoint.com/tag/html5-dev-center"><img src="images/sitePics/sitePic_HTML502.png" alt="sitepoint.com - HTML5 Development Center"></a>

                        <h3>The HTML5 Development Center at sitepoint.com</h3>
                        <p>One of many sections on the Sitepoint website that hosts articles related to web development.  This page has a wide variety of articles that relate to HTML5.
                        <a href="http://www.sitepoint.com/tag/html5-dev-center">read more</a></p>
                        <div>HTML5</div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="html5Tab03" class="topicContent">
                        <a href="http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author"><img src="images/sitePics/sitePic_HTML503.png" alt="The W3C HTML 5 Reference"></a>

                        <h3>The W3C HTML 5 Reference</h3>
                        <p>A web developer's guide to HTML 5 drafted by the W3C.  Covers most everything related to the HTML 5 specification including all of the tags, etc...
                        <a href="http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author">read more</a></p>
                        <div>HTML5</div>
                    </div>
                </div>   <!-- end div#html5Tabs -->


                <div id="css3Tabs" class="contentContainer">
                    <div id="css3Tab01" class="topicContent">
                        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/css3/default.asp"><img src="images/sitePics/sitePic_CSS301.png" alt="Learn CSS3 at www.w3schools.com"></a>

                        <h3>Learn CSS3 at w3schools.com</h3>
                        <p>Go through a CSS3 tutorial and learn about new effects available and what browsers they work in.  There is also a CSS3 reference on this site for selectors, attribute/value pairs, etc...
                        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/css3/default.asp">read more</a></p>
                        <div>CSS3</div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="css3Tab02" class="topicContent">
                        <a href="http://www.css3.info"><img src="images/sitePics/sitePic_CSS302.png" alt="CSS3.info - Everything you need to know about CSS3"></a>

                        <h3>CSS3.info - Everything you need to know about CSS3</h3>
                        <p>This site contains a preview of CSS3 attributes and their values along with many articles on CSS3 topics.  It also allows you to test various CSS3 selectors in your browser to see if they are compatible.
                        <a href="http://www.css3.info">read more</a></p>
                        <div>CSS3</div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="css3Tab03" class="topicContent">
                        <a href="http://css3please.com"><img src="images/sitePics/sitePic_CSS303.png" alt="css3please.com"></a>

                        <h3>The CSS3, please website</h3>
                        <p>CSS3, please is a no-frills site showing examples of new CSS3 selectors and attribute/value pairs that you can copy and paste right into your browser.  It includes all of the variants that work in any browsers that support CSS3.
                        <a href="http://css3please.com">read more</a></p>
                        <div>CSS3</div>
                    </div>
                </div>   <!-- end div#css3Tabs -->


                <div id="jqueryTabs" class="contentContainer">
                    <div id="jqueryTab01" class="topicContent">
                        <a href="http://www.jquery.com"><img src="images/sitePics/sitePic_jQuery01.png" alt="The jQuery website - www.jquery.com"></a>

                        <h3>The jQuery website - "write less, do more"</h3>
                        <p>Learn about and download the jQuery JavaScript library at www.jquery.com.  jQuery's purpose is to allow you to more easily traverse HTML documents, handle events, and animate content via  easy to understand code.
                        <a href="http://www.jquery.com">read more</a></p>
                        <div>jQuery</div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="jqueryTab02" class="topicContent">
                        <a href="http://api.jquery.com"><img src="images/sitePics/sitePic_jQuery02.png" alt="Help documentation for jQuery methods at api.jquery.com"></a>

                        <h3>The jQuery API - documentation of jQuery methods</h3>
                        <p>This extremely helpful website contains help documentation for all of jQuery's built-in methods.  The help pages are laid out in a easy to read fashion yet give very good depth of information.
                        <a href="http://api.jquery.com">read more</a></p>
                        <div>jQuery</div>
                    </div>

                </div>   <!-- end div#jqueryTabs -->


                <div id="phpTabs" class="contentContainer">
                    <div id="phpTab01" class="topicContent">
                        <a href="http://www.jquery.com"><img src="images/sitePics/sitePic_php01.png" alt="The jQuery website - www.jquery.com"></a>

                        <h3>The jQuery website - "write less, do more"</h3>
                        <p>Learn about and download the jQuery JavaScript library at www.jquery.com.  jQuery's purpose is to allow you to more easily traverse HTML documents, handle events, and animate content via  easy to understand code.
                        <a href="http://www.jquery.com">read more</a></p>
                        <div>PHP</div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="phpTab02" class="topicContent">
                        <a href="http://api.jquery.com"><img src="images/sitePics/sitePic_php02.png" alt="Help documentation for jQuery methods at api.jquery.com"></a>

                        <h3>The jQuery API - documentation of jQuery methods</h3>
                        <p>This extremely helpful website contains help documentation for all of jQuery's built-in methods.  The help pages are laid out in a easy to read fashion yet give very good depth of information.
                        <a href="http://api.jquery.com">read more</a></p>
                        <div>PHP</div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="phpTab03" class="topicContent">
                        <a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops"><img src="images/sitePics/sitePic_php03.png" alt="Tutorials and articles on web design/development including jQuery, HTML5, and CSS3"></a>

                        <h3>Tutorials on jQuery, HTML5, and CSS3</h3>
                        <p>Codrops is a web development blog that publishes articles and tutorials about web design, programming and usability. The team of Codrops is dedicated to provide useful and qualitative content that is free of charge.
                        <a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops">read more</a></p>
                        <div>PHP</div>
                    </div>
                </div>   <!-- end div#phpTabs -->


                <div id="flashTabs" class="contentContainer">
                    <div id="flashTab01" class="topicContent">
                        <a href="http://www.jquery.com"><img src="images/sitePics/sitePic_flash01.png" alt="The jQuery website - www.jquery.com"></a>

                        <h3>The jQuery website - "write less, do more"</h3>
                        <p>Learn about and download the jQuery JavaScript library at www.jquery.com.  jQuery's purpose is to allow you to more easily traverse HTML documents, handle events, and animate content via  easy to understand code.
                        <a href="http://www.jquery.com">read more</a></p>
                        <div>Flash</div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="flashTab02" class="topicContent">
                        <a href="http://api.jquery.com"><img src="images/sitePics/sitePic_flash02.png" alt="Help documentation for jQuery methods at api.jquery.com"></a>

                        <h3>The jQuery API - documentation of jQuery methods</h3>
                        <p>This extremely helpful website contains help documentation for all of jQuery's built-in methods.  The help pages are laid out in a easy to read fashion yet give very good depth of information.
                        <a href="http://api.jquery.com">read more</a></p>
                        <div>Flash</div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="flashTab03" class="topicContent">
                        <a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops"><img src="images/sitePics/sitePic_flash03.png" alt="Tutorials and articles on web design/development including jQuery, HTML5, and CSS3"></a>

                        <h3>Tutorials on jQuery, HTML5, and CSS3</h3>
                        <p>Codrops is a web development blog that publishes articles and tutorials about web design, programming and usability. The team of Codrops is dedicated to provide useful and qualitative content that is free of charge.
                        <a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops">read more</a></p>
                        <div>Flash</div>
                    </div>
                </div>   <!-- end div#flashTabs -->

            </div>  <!-- end div#content -->
```

This is what I have for my JQuery...

```
$(function() {

$('#contentWrap').css({height: '2em'});
$('#leftSideBar').css({height: '25em'});

$('header nav ul li a').on('click', function(event) {

    // this newTopicContent is returned as a string
    var newTopicContent = $(this).text();

    $('#topic').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $('#topic').text(newTopicContent).fadeIn(500);
    });

    var newContentID = $(this).attr('id') + 'Tabs';

    $(newContentID, '.contentContainer').slideDown();

});
});
```

I am having trouble understand how to use newContentID to select the appropriate .contentContainer div that you should slide down into place. I would appreciate some insight.

Comment: Don't you want `.html()` not `.text()`?

Comment: For one thing, none of your JQuery selectors (`#contentWrap` or `#topic`) seem to match up with actual objects in your HTML ...

Comment: That is because I didn't post all my html just the snippets that I need to show for someone to understand what I am ask and help me with what I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to select the right contentContainer, then change your last 2 lines to

```
var newContentID = '#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'Tabs';
$(newContentID).slideDown();
```

`$(this).attr('id')` is grabbing the id from whichever link you clicked on (ex. "html5") and then appends "#" to the beginning and "Tabs" to the end of that id to make, for example, `#html5Tabs`. With this jQuery can select the element with ID "html5Tabs" and slide that down.

Comment: This works excellent. I have tried it and it works. I have beating my head  for the last 2 days to get it to work. Thanks